# How to iterate over a jquery loop slowly, and replace placeholder text each time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, placeholder

I've tried a few different things such as setting a timeout and calling a function every few seconds, but I can seem to get the following to work:

```
var searchText = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];


    for(x = 0; x < searchText.length; x++){

        // set the placeholder text
        jQuery('.banner .search-field').attr('placeholder', searchText[x]);



    }
```

The above iterates over the values in the array but too quickly for the user to see.  I can see it's working correctly by checking console.log

I've tried using the delay function but can't get it to work. Is there any way to get this to delay between the updates?

Comment: Do you want it to loop once or a continuous loop?

Comment: loop once would be fine

Comment: `setTimeout()` will work

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with with a simple `for` loop and `setTimeout`,

```
var secs = 5;
var elem = jQuery('.banner .search-field');
for(x = 1; x <= secs; x++) {
  setTimeout(function(x) {
    elem.attr('placeholder', x);
  }, x * 1000, x);
}
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Lvjyrzu6/)